# Android - Make function false/not run

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a `setOnClickListener` on two buttons that just runs the code in two functions.

I want to create a safe call so when I click the buttons the app doesn't crash. I thought I would have to make them false or something, but apparently it doesn't work.

How should I do it?

Thanks

```
 if (weightView.text.isEmpty() && percentageView.text.isEmpty()) { 
   calculation() == false                                    
   lbsCalculation() == false                                     
 } else {                           
   calculation()                                                 
   lbsCalculation()                                              
 }
```

These are my two clickListeners

```
calculateBtn.setOnClickListener{
        calculation()
    }

    lbsCalculationBtn.setOnClickListener{
        lbsCalculation()
    }
```

Functions:

```
fun calculation () {
           var weightValue = weightView.text.toString().toInt()
           var percentageValue = percentageView.text.toString().toInt()
           var result = (weightValue * percentageValue) / 100.toDouble()
           var resultFormat = "%.1f KG".format(result)
           resultView.text = resultFormat.toString()


   }

    fun lbsCalculation() {
        var weightValue = weightView.text.toString().toInt()
        var percentageValue = percentageView.text.toString().toInt()
        var result = ((weightValue * percentageValue) / 100) * 2.2.toDouble()
        var resultFormat = "%.1f LBS".format(result)
        resultView.text = resultFormat.toString()

    }
```

=================

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJTCF.png)

Comment: let me see those 2 function.

Comment: Added @Orvenito

Comment: check my answer and tell me if you I need to add something, my solution will 100% work.

Comment: didn't work....

Comment: can you comment on my answer on how you did it.

Comment: First of all: What are you trying to achieve? And what exactly is the error you are getting and when does it happen?

Answer (score -1):

**Do it inside your method. Something like this:**

```
public class calculation(String weightView, String percentageView){
//you make a condition that should do something if strings are empty
if(weightView && percentageView == null)
//DO WHAT YOU WANT
}else{
//Show an alert or something that your EditText is empty.
}
```

and should call it in like this:

```
calculateBtn.setOnClickListener{
    calculation(weightView.getText.toString(),percentageView.getText.toString())    
}
```

**======EDIT=======**

Your function should look like this:

```
fun calculation(weightValue: String,percentageValue: String)
{
    if(weightValue == null && percentageValue == null ){
    var myWeightValue = weightValue.toInt();
    var myPercentageValue = percentageValue.toInt();
    var result = (myWeightValue * myPercentageValue) / 100
    var resultFormat = "%.1f KG".format(result) 
    resultView.text = resultFormat
    }
    else {
    **SHOW A MESSAGE LIKE A TOAST OR ALERTDIALOG TO LET THE USER KNOW THAT WEIGHT AND PERCENTAGE IS REQUIRED**
    }
}

fun lbsCalculation() {
        var weightValue = weightView.text.toString().toInt()
        var percentageValue = percentageView.text.toString().toInt()
        var result = ((weightValue * percentageValue) / 100) * 2.2
        var resultFormat = "%.1f LBS".format(result)
        resultView.text = resultFormat

    }
```

Your onClick should look like this:

```
calculateBtn.setOnClickListener{
    calculation(weightView.text,percentageView.text)    
}
```